# getting list of camera or render globals from maya scene file without opening scene in maya

Tags: python, maya, autodesk

is it possible with python to read a maya scene file without opening and get list of camera's or render globals setting or perform some operations on it. 
I need this so that if their are multiple scene files I do not have to open each maya scene and just tweak it from a python script, I would really appreciate if some one can show how to start rest I will do  myself...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its possible, may just not be practical. A Maya ASCII file is pretty trivial to parse. A Maya binary file not so much. It may be a bit premature to discuss there matters.

First things first. Maya does offer a batch mode, the batch mode does not use up a full license. It still opens a full Maya environment but no GUI. This is the perfect platform to inject scripts. It doesn't really fulfill your request of not opening Maya but it fulfills all other requirements. There are a few ways for using this batch mode. But mostly it boils down to two general methods.

Method 1, using *mayabatch*: The mayaXX/bin/ directory contains a command called *mayabatch*. You can simply call this from a cmd/shell batch file/shellscript. This is a extremely simple way of calling existing scripts. Assuming *mayabatch* is in the path of your environment and your script is in Maya script path. Lets assume for simplicity that your script looks as follows (demo.py):

```
import maya.cmds as cmd

def func():
    print cmd.ls()

# we want this to execute on import
func()
```

Now calling this for one file under windows would look as following:

```
mayabatch -command "python(""import demo"") " -file filename.ma
```

calling this over all Maya in the current folder files would then be simply:

```
for %i in (*.ma) do mayabatch -command "python(""import demo"") " -file %i
```

The quoting rules are a bit different on mac and Linux but should be easy to find. reefer to the manual of your shell.

Method 2, using *mayapy* and standalone:

Now you can also directly call the python script with mayapy. Its located in the same directory as mayabtach. Tough the standalone can be called form other python interpreters too if you include Maya modules in the system path. Now the script must be a bit changed so it does the same thing (demo_direct.py):

```
#init maya
import maya.standalone
maya.standalone.initialize( name='python' )
import maya.cmds as cmd
import glob

def func():
    print cmd.ls(shapes=True)

for file in glob.glob('*.m[ab]'):
    cmd.file( file, o=True )
    func()
```

call this form command line with:

```
mayapy demo_driect.py
```

Neither of these methods load Mayas graphical user interface. So you can not call stuff like playblast etc. Since they rely on a GUI, and thus a full Maya license. Nothing says you can not do a similar load loop in the GUI as above.

Then for the methods without actually loading Maya. This is a bit tricky. Doing this is not necessarily worth it since the batch nodes are pretty fast as they don't eventuate everything on load. A sample script that parses a Maya ASCII file for frame ranges. You might find it useful. See following [post](http://www.creativecrash.com/forums/python/topics/findout-playrange-from-a-bunch-of-maya-asci-files--2#discussion_post_306288). For Maya binary files there is a python module in [cgKit](http://cgkit.sourceforge.net/doc2/index.html) that will help you read Maya binary chunks. Unfortunately it doesn't do anything for understanding the data.

Comment: i cannot use the first method because i want to read the camera is the scene file, and the startFrame & endFrame from render globals, but as far as second method is concerned let say i get all shapes by cmds.ls(shapes=True) the how should I append the list of shapes i got to QComboBox ?

Comment: @san, you can use the first method. I'm just illustrating how you launch many scripts because your not terribly specific on what you want to do, therefore i assumed you know how to script maya. Obviously if you want to list all cameras you'd change the print cmd.ls() to print cmd.ls(type='camera'). As for the QComboBox that's not what you asked. When you ask try to keep it simply on the line of what you want and dont decorate it with lots of stuff that you don't know may be in the solution.

Comment: import subprocess
    
    subprocess.call()
    
    import os
    import maya.standalone
    import maya.cmds as cmds
    fileToOpen="I:/scenes/san_telus_pan_v009.ma"
    def getCams(phileToOpen):
        maya.standalone.initialize(name='python')
        cmds.file(phileToOpen, force=True,open=True)
        cams=cmds.ls(type="camera")
        return cams
    
    getCams(fileToOpen)
I want to execute the above function in readMayaFile.py from [RenderUI.py][1]
so that I get return list of cams in the QComboBox 
  [1]: http://pastebin.com/9gfYaWRV

Comment: Ok yes I can get this. Its just that you have pretty well destroyed the purpose of stackoverflow. Your not supposed to discuss things in here. Your supposed to ask concise questions so that the question makes sense as a reference. Stackoverflow is trying to build a faq. So if you want to alter the resolution of a question then you need to alter your question to reflect the answer you need. IF you want to generally discuss things go over to some forum. Ive been known to hang on creativecrash.com if you want to expand things otherwise revise your question to fit stackoverflow better.

Comment: As for your question. omit the  subprocess lines omit last line. Then type import yourPythonFilename in your main file and then call: cameras = yourPythonFilename.getCams('I:/scenes/san_telus_pan_v009.ma') in your main file. But comment fields aren't good for this kinds of discussion because they aren't supposed to happen here.

Comment: I had subprocess written because i was experimenting something but forgot to remove before posting here, sorry, now i have posted on creative crash with same subject

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20815/discussion-between-san-and-joojaa)